# Import project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I imported a project into Eclipse and then deleted it, Now I am trying to import the same project once again, but Eclipse says Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace. I'm not sure how to import that project now.

Comment: Try to open eclipse in other workspace and import project there

Comment: remove existing project from workspace or change the workspace to different location

Comment: I removed that project so I don't understand why eclipse says they already exist in the workspace when they are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Right click inside Eclipse `Navigator` view then use **Restore from Local History...** option to restore your projects.